# toString method giving me null pointer exception

Tags: android

I'm using HttpURLConnection to parse the jsonResponse. It does a great work most of the time. But sometimes, it is giving 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference error in this line: "jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());" and then the app crashes. I'm using try and catch here but still the app crashes. why the app is crashing btw? How can I solve this problem?

Error log

```
11-06 16:31:59.312 21887-21887/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.zzz.com.zz, PID: 21887
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
   at com.zzz.com.zz.jobschedulers.MainActivity$LoginTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:761)
   at com.zzz.com.zz.jobschedulers.MainActivity$LoginTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:664)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

code

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL("http://zzzz.com");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(25000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(25000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<String, String>();


            h1.put("username", email);
            h1.put("password", password);
            writer.write(getPostDataString(h1));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("upload gps", "uploaded");
            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
                return response;
            } else {
                response = "";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
            responseMsg = jsonResponse.getString("message");

            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                Log.e("response ", response + "");

                JSONObject jsonResponse1 = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("data");
                String userId = jsonResponse1.getString("user_id");
                Log.e("userId", userId + "");
                if (userId != null) {
                    SharedPreferences abc = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = abc.edit();
                    editor2.putString("userId", userId);
                    editor2.apply();

                } else {
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LiveTrack.class);
                i.putExtra("userId", userId);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {
                Log.e("response", "onloginfailed");
                validate();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Smth went wrong. Please check your network and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Json", "execption" + e);
        }
    }
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: that means you are getting null in response. first you need to make there should not be null  return in response

Comment: Check if(response!=null) response can be null in case of connection failed

Comment: Might be because of this `JSONObject jsonResponse = null;` in postexecute

Comment: @RakeshPolo nope, it's `response.toString()` that fails

Answer (score 0):

So your question is why it's crashing even though you have set the Try/Catch. So my answer is you have catch the `JSONException` exception and that is for Json-Parsing related.

So use Try/Catch as below.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
        responseMsg = jsonResponse.getString("message");

        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            Log.e("response ", response + "");

            JSONObject jsonResponse1 = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("data");
            String userId = jsonResponse1.getString("user_id");
            Log.e("userId", userId + "");
            if (userId != null) {
                SharedPreferences abc = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = abc.edit();
                editor2.putString("userId", userId);
                editor2.apply();

            } else {
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LiveTrack.class);
            i.putExtra("userId", userId);
            startActivity(i);

        } else {
            Log.e("response", "onloginfailed");
            validate();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Smth went wrong. Please check your network and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Json", "execption" + e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Generic", "execption" + e);
    }
```

Please note in above I have added one more Catch with generic `Exception`.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: This is not the issue, the error explicitly complains about `toString()` being run on a null object. Catching generic exceptions doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is somewhere else. Your `onPostExecute(String result)` executes the following:

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

However, at the end of your `doInBackground()` you have explicitly said:

```
return null;
```

`doInBackground()` is supposed to return a Result (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...))). You're returning null, so in your `onPostExecute()` you always do this if the connection fails:

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(null.toString());
```

Hence, your app crashes and Android runtime complains about you trying to run `toString()` on null. To fix the issue, you have to return the `String result` you want in `doInBackground()`

Comment: That said, you should check if `response == null` in `onPostExecute()` before calling `toString()` on it anyway. You should also not return `null` as a response. Just return a empty String (`""`)  and in `onPostExecute()` check if the response isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

on `onPostExecute()` before `jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());` enter this: `if(response == null)return;`

Comment: You should probably handle the situation and at least add a message that the connection failed before returning